# Theme gnome panel handles in flashback session

Tags: 14.04, themes, gtk, gnome-classic

I'm using the the gnome flashback session (metacity) in Ubuntu 14.04.
The default theme is the ambient theme. If you set a gnome panel to not expand, the handles are looking ugly:
[image: As can be seen in this screenshot.]
How can I theme/change this?

Answer (score -1):

#### 1 - install ubuntu

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa 
$ sudo apt-get update 
$ sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

#### 2 - find & configure

Go to app search look for 'ubuntu-tweak' .
Open it then .
go to tweaks .
Then Unity .
Make it comfortable 'read then edit'
[image]

if that didnt workout with you try to reset unity then configure it 
**reset unity**

```
$ unity-reset
$ setsid unity
```

Comment: Are you sure? The problem above has nothing to do with unity.

Comment: i'd like to try if i were u

Comment: I tried it, but there is nothing there.